# How to initialize multiple variables of some type in one line

Tags: swift

I want to achieve something like

```
var a, b, c: MyType = MyType()
```

but this line doesn't compile because compiler treats the type annotation `MyType` is only for variable `c` thus `a` and `b` are missing either type annotation or a initial value for type inference.

Both of followings are legal :

```
// legal but verbose
var a = MyType()
var b = MyType()
var c = MyType()

// legal but verbose to initialize
var a, b, c: MyType
a = MyType()
b = MyType()
c = MyType()
```

These two styles I can think of are both legal but somehow verbose, especially if there are dozens of variables of same type.

Is there any elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: IMO, declaring multiple variables on the same line looks unswifty.

Comment: If you have a default value, the closest is use of the tuple synatx.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two options in Swift: commas or tuples.

With commas separated statements:

```
var a = MyType(), b = MyType(), c = MyType()
```

With a tuple statement:

```
var (a, b, c) = (MyType(), MyType(), MyType())
```

Also, but discouraged, you can make multiple statements on one line using semi-colons:

```
var a = MyType(); var b = MyType(); var c = MyType()
```

Comment: Wonder if var a, b, c: MyType needs !

Comment: @carlosvega.me `var a, b, c: MyType` is not about initializing variables (it's just about declaring). You don't need `!` if you properly initialize those in your `init`.

Answer (score 9):

> You can declare multiple constants or multiple variables on a single
>   line, separated by commas:
>
> ```
> var a = "", b = "", c = ""
> ```
>
> NOTE
>
> > If a stored value in your code is not going to change, always declare
> >     it as a constant with the let keyword. Use variables only for storing
> >     values that need to be able to change.

Documentation [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

In your case:

```
var a = MyType(), b = MyType(), c = MyType()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5+

Some possible solution (maybe worth it if you're planning on doing this several times) is writting a struct to initialize your values and a method (or computed property) on that struct to return the individual components unpacked. You could also add a typealias for improved readability:

```
typealias MyTypeTrio = (a: MyType, b: MyType, c: MyType)

struct MyTypesPack {
    var a, b, c: MyType

    init(a: MyType = .init(), b: MyType = .init(), c: MyType = .init()) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    }

    var components: MyTypeTrio { (a, b, c) }
}
```

Usage:

```
...

let (a, b, c) = MyPackTrio().components
```

Of course, if you don't need that much granularity of control you may as well just add a static (or not) helper method anywhere (but preferrably in a namespace, such as in an extension of MyType, for instance).

You coud simply write:

```
extension MyType {
    static let trio: MyTypeTrio = (a: MyType(), b: MyType(), c: MyType())
}
```

and then just use it as:

```
var (a, b, c) = MyType.trio
```

---

I ran into a similar situation recently regarding color components.

Here's what I did then:

```
typealias RGBA = (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)

struct RGBAColor {
    var red, green, blue, alpha: CGFloat

    init(red: CGFloat = 0, green: CGFloat = 0, blue: CGFloat = 0, alpha: CGFloat = 0) {
        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue
        self.alpha = alpha
    }

    var components: RGBA { (red, green, blue, alpha) }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

MyType = MyType()
var MyType: [Any] = [Int, "String", "abc", Double, etc..]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

More smarter way to do this is

```
let type = (MyType(), MyType(), MyType())
var (a, b, c) = type
```